# Blocking sites using /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, cache, dns

To fight against my procrastination I changed /etc/hosts on my Ubuntu (11.10) laptop. The /etc/hosts looks now like

```
127.0.0.1 facebook.com  
127.0.0.1 plus.google.com  
127.0.0.1 twitter.com
```

and many more time-eaters in it!

But if I type now facebook.com in my browser it *still* works.

Is there a DNS cache or something?

Comment: By the way, you can put multiple entries on one line--`127.0.0.1 facebook.com plus.google.com twitter.com stackoverflow.com` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you perhaps going to `www.facebook.com` rather than `facebook.com`? You probably want to block `www.` variants as well.

Comment: such an easy answer...
i was searching really long for deleting the dns cache...
thanks for your help!